# File download in Struts 2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I am trying to download a file from my web server running Struts2, Hibernate and Spring but I am always getting this exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputName] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult.doExecute(StreamResult.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:34)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
```

I have checked the `inputName` parameter and debugged the project to find out that `InputStream` is not `null`.

**This is the download class:**

```
inputName= new ByteArrayInputStream(mf.getFileContent());
```

and this is Struts 2 mapping:

```xml
       <action name="downloadfile" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.DownloadFile">
            <result name="success" type="stream">
                
                <param name="inputName">inputName</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=${fileName}</param>
                <param name="contentType">${contentType}</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
                <param name="contentLength">${contentLength}</param>
                <param name="allowCaching">false</param>
                
            </result>
            <result name="input">/user/files.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Is the exception because of `ByteArrayInputStream` or any other reason. I have public getter and setter method for all variables and I have checked that none of them is `null`.

**EDIT:**

**`DownloadFile` class:**

```
package com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.dao.FilesBo;
import com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.entities.Files;
import com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.entities.Users;
import com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.util.MyFile;
import com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.util.Operations;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware;


public class DownloadFile extends ActionSupport implements ServletContextAware{
    
    private long fid;
    private String contentType;
    private long contentLength;
    private String fileName;
    private InputStream inputName;
    
    
    private ServletContext context;
    private String downloadStatus;
    private String downloadpassword;
    private List fileList;
    private Map<String,Object> session;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    

    public List getFileList() {
        return fileList;
    }

    public void setFileList(List fileList) {
        this.fileList = fileList;
    }
    

    public String getDownloadStatus() {
        return downloadStatus;
    }

    public void setDownloadStatus(String downloadStatus) {
        this.downloadStatus = downloadStatus;
    }

    public String getDownloadpassword() {
        return downloadpassword;
    }

    public void setDownloadpassword(String downloadpassword) {
        this.downloadpassword = downloadpassword;
    }
    
    public String getStatus() {
        return downloadStatus;
    }

    public void setStatus(String downloadStatus) {
        this.downloadStatus = downloadStatus;
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private FilesBo fbo;
    
    @Autowired
    private Operations operation;

    public Operations getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    public void setOperation(Operations operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    
    public FilesBo getFbo() {
        return fbo;
    }

    public void setFbo(FilesBo fbo) {
        this.fbo = fbo;
    }
    

    public long getFid() {
        return fid;
    }

    public void setFid(long fid) {
        this.fid = fid;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    public long getContentLength() {
        return contentLength;
    }

    public void setContentLength(long contentLength) {
        this.contentLength = contentLength;
    }
    

    public InputStream getInputName() {
        return inputName;
    }

    public void setInputName(InputStream inputName) {
        this.inputName = inputName;
    }

    
    @Override
    public String execute(){
        String response;
        int a=10;
        try
        {
            session=ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
            Users u= (Users) session.get("user");
            long uid=u.getUid();
            fileList=fbo.getAllFiles(uid);
            Files f=getFbo().getFileWithData(getFid());
            MyFile mf=new MyFile();
            mf.setFileContent(f.getFileData());
            mf.setFileContentType(f.getFileContentType());
            mf.setFileHash(f.getFileHash());
            mf.setFileName(f.getFileName());
            mf.setFileSize(f.getFileSize());
            mf.setPassword(downloadpassword);
            mf=operation.decrypt(mf);
            
            fileName=mf.getFileName();
            contentLength=mf.getFileSize();
            contentType=mf.getFileContentType();
            
            inputName=new ByteArrayInputStream(mf.getFileContent());
            
            response=ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            if(e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Message has been altered or password incorrect"))
            {
                downloadStatus="Message has been altered or incorrect password. Try again.";
            }
            response=ActionSupport.INPUT;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            downloadStatus="Some error occured. Try Again";
            response=ActionSupport.INPUT;
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.context=servletContext;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Show your `DownloadFile` action.

Comment: @AleksandrM see the EDITS

Comment: @user3172529 Your `inputName` parameter is not of type `InputStream`. Check the value in the context.

Comment: I think try changing that `inputName` to some other name..

Comment: @RomanC There was some error with the inputName as well as contentLength. Apprently I was setting contentLength to a value more than actual byte data and then when I download the file at 99.99 % I was getting this failed download error.

Comment: Unrelated, but the action's `execute` method is doing far too much. Break it down further, something closer to https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/8090865 (untested), and even that should be broken down a little bit further.

Comment: @DaveNewton yup thanx for diverting my attention to this issue will have a look at this class execute method as well as others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, change `inputName` to `inputStream`. Like this

```
private InputStream inputStream;

public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}

public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    this.inputStream= inputStream;
}
```

the default setting for the parameter `inputName` is `inputStream`, so, you could remove that. Also note that parameter's names in result are looked up in the value stack. So, if you expose a getter like `getInputName` in the action means that you want to override the value in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the getInputName() method does not return null, if it returns null, this exception will occur.

This exception's description is misleading, it will make you feel that the name of your inputName param configuration is wrong. However, the actual reason is getInputName()'s return InputStream is null.

Answer (score -1):

```
            <param name="inputName">inputName</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=${fileName}</param>
            <param name="contentType">${contentType}</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            <param name="contentLength">${contentLength}</param>
            <param name="allowCaching">false</param>


             *<!--add a iuputStream-->
            <param name="inputStream">inputName</param>*

        </result>
        <result name="input">/user/files.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: please explain your answer a little?